# combined VPN shortcut

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, shortcuts

After creating a VPN connection shortcut for the desktop -- and also creating a shortcut for the private IP (10.1.2.145) that I go to *after* establishing the connection -- I began to wonder if it is possible to combine these two commands/shortcuts, so that a single shortcut would both establish the connection and open 10.1.2.145 in Windows Explorer. Anyone ever thought of this or tried to make it work?

using Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with any number of shortcuts through a batch script. It's not really a shortcut, but it works.

For the sake of simplicity, and also because I don't really know what the shortcuts are pointing to, you should keep both shortcut files and reference those directly. Store them in a directory that you won't be moving or renaming (the desktop is fine, but that's just unnecessary clutter).

Then, make a .bat file in a text editor. Just put the full path of the first shortcut on the first line of the file, and in the second line put

```
C:\Windows\explorer.exe "10.1.2.145"
```

This will open the IP in Windows Explorer.

The full batch file would look something like

```
C:\path\to\vpn\shortcut.lnk
C:\Windows\explorer.exe "10.1.2.145"
```

Save the file with a .bat extension and place it wherever you want. Double click to run it.

**Note**

If you find that the VPN doesn't have enough time to establish before Explorer tries to open the IP address, add a line in between the two shortcuts that waits a few seconds:

```
timeout 5
```

Comment: Good stuff, Thank you. I tried to +1 for you, but I don't have enough reputation yet. .bat works, except right after the first shortcut executes, a dialogue box pops up and I must manually hit Connect. Don't know if that could be included in the script, but as-is it's still quicker. Code so far:

    C:\Users\username\Desktop\VPN-Connection.lnk  
    timeout 10  
    C:\Windows\explorer.exe "\\10.1.2.145"

Comment: Good grief, one thing after another. Can't put blocks of code in commments; can't do an Answer until tomorrow (for better display of the code), then my first comment can only be edited for five minutes, so can't fix it or remove it.

Comment: update: it all works together now, I forgot that "prompt for username ... " can be turned OFF in the VPN connection settings. Thanks again. I wish I could +1 for you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you're satisfied with the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.